# Java Days & Bookings

Tags: java, date

Ok this is an extension of a question I asked about earlier yet this is the next step that is unclear to me. Everything else will be ready and this part is driving me mad! some members provided great help and I already made progress with that info, but this is just another obstacle.

I am creating a booking object (as was suggested) that will have a start date and end date. each booking will also have a number of seats associated with it (that I require to reserve). The total available number of seats any given day 46 (as the total capacity of the hall is 46 seats).

so in assumption that I have a booking to be made in the system, and start date is 1st jan and end date is 10th jan. **The question is how can I check the remaining seats in all those days between the range to see if requested number could be hosted or not?** and then when the second booking is made, it will have to see that the days in this range already have less than 46 and decrement further if possible to host the reservation.

one of the members, and I appreciate his effort, gladly contributed a method to compare if this booking is after or before the existing bookings. The code provided is here:

```
public boolean overlapsWithExisting(Booking booking) {
final Date early = booking.getStart();
final Date late = booking.getEnd();
for(Booking existing : existingBookings) {
    if(!(early.isAfter(existing.getEnd() || late.isBefore(existing.getStart()))
        return true;
}
return false;
}
```

I just want to know how to associate 46 with each day and keep record of days that are decremented by bookings.

Thanks and reallllllly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest wrapping the Date object in a type of data structure which is specific to your application : I believe you have a specific type of information for your business logic which can be expressed in a Map.

Thus, you can create a TreeMap.

```
TreeMap<Date,Integer> myBookings = new TreeMap<Date,Integer>();
```

And set all dates to 46 :

```
for(Date d : allDates)
   myBookings.put(d,46);
```

Now, when you add a person to the room on a given date, you simply edit the map :

```
myBookings.put(date,myBookings.get(date)-1);
```

Thus, the map data structure wraps all dates in the range and stores the number of seats available.

Comment: by all the dates, you mean the dates within range start date and end date?

Comment: and sorry could u elaborate more on the myBookings.get(date)-1) part? is that carrying out a subtraction of 1 seat from total on that date?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL one would do the following to find blocking bookings:

```
SELECT *
FROM bookings
WHERE startt < :end AND endt >= :start
LIMIT 0, 1
```

This can be done in java too; having the bookings sorted by date would help.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to the days problem whereby I could reflect the effect of other bookings...

Comment: Sorry, I tried to simplify the problem by a data centric approach. The coding in Java would involve having N seats empty during that period. I wonder whether anyone will answer that with code.

Comment: Okay, another data centric tip: maybe have a parallel (=redundant) data structure for seats and their occupation; you could then do Seat.isFree(Date from, Date till).

Comment: Joop sounds like an interesting approach..although the treemap suggested earlier would actually perform the wrapping required. As long as I can have a relation between dates and seats, I believe operations on structures would be very similar. Also a link should be created between bookings and dates

Comment: Any hint of how the dates (i.e. every possible day in a year) could be generated within the data structure?